# Django session is not generated using JWT and graphene

Tags: django, django-models, graphql, graphene-python

I'm new learning graphene with django, and as the documentation says, I have this class:

```
import graphql_jwt

class Mutations(graphene.ObjectType):
    token_auth = graphql_jwt.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()
    verify_token = graphql_jwt.Verify.Field()
    refresh_token = graphql_jwt.Refresh.Field()
```

but calling the tockenAuth mutation, even when the token is correcty generates because the user and password are correct, I don't see anything saved in the session table:

```
Session.objects.all()
```

is always empty

I'm checking the session for login out any user. So, how can I generate the Session entry from the authToken mutation call and what's the correct/better way to login/logout users using graphql_jwt?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

JWT is an alternative to sessions - it is another way to authenticate a request so you do not need sessions if you use JWT.

JWT also does not create any kind of information in database - you can just use cryptography to verify that the token is legitimate. To authenticate with JWT include `JSONWebTokenBackend` in your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` as described [here](https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt).

Read more about jwt [here](https://medium.com/vandium-software/5-easy-steps-to-understanding-json-web-tokens-jwt-1164c0adfcec).

Comment: Hi AmerllicA - write me to don.skoy.333@gmail.com